# Dealing with the "overflow" of data in a ring buffer

Tags: c, embedded, uart

So I have a ring buffer that's used inside the USART's ISR to stores the user input and upon receiving `\r`, it calls the application callback where I parse the elements into a local buffer between the head and tail indices, but I see the following issues:

- the old data in the local buffer stays. So in case, the incoming data is shorter than the previous data, you'll see something like `'n','e','w','o','l','d'`.

Determining the length of the new data would help cause then I could just take the substring of it but determining the length by subtracting the head index from the tail won't work in case there was a wraparound.

E.g:

```
Ring buffer size: 9
Head index: 7
Tail index: 1
```

you get 3 more new chars and the head index becomes 1. So computing the length by mere subtraction won't work.

**tl;dr** - the issue i'm trying to get around is being able to separate the new data from the old data in a local buffer (which contains the parsed data between the head and tail index). The same issue will occur if the user inputs more data than the length of the ring buffer i.e it would override the old data. But with index, even you have a large enough buffer, you'd still see the same issue eventually.

Answer (score 4):

That's why a ring buffer has *two* pointers; a write pointer and a read pointer. When writing, you advance the write pointer. When reading, you advance the read pointer. If the write pointer overtakes the read pointer, then you drop some data and signal an overrun (or you stop the process that's producing the data, if possible). If the read pointer overtakes the write pointer, then you tell the reading process that there isn't any more data available to be read.

Comment: would you read the data into a local buffer (for parsing) as soon as it's put into the buffer or wait till a specified char is received, which in my case is `\r`? does that reduce the chance of overrun?

Comment: @Pokloha You should have two halves to the driver. The "low"-half handles the hardware and is responsible for putting bytes into the buffer. Only it is allowed to modify the write pointer. The "high"-hlaf handles the getchar() function and uses the read pointer. Only the high"-half can modify the read pointer. Your main code only should access the buffer via the "high"-half. If you don't have an O/S then just sit in a loop until you have read out "a line" (the \r, I suppose, determines that fact.) Then go process it. Your "main" code should have its own buffer to copy the chars into.

Comment: @Pokloha I read data into a local buffer for parsing simply because I was using C library tokenizing functions which only work in a linear array and it was too difficult to modify things to parse something that crossed the buffer wraparound. If you could parse it directly in the ring buffer, you would save memory (and possibly time if the overhead wasn't too high). If you have a termination character, you might choose to reject the entire recent message if an overflow occurs (i.e. a \r is not received before an overflow is detected).

Comment: In my case, I had a extra pointers that marked the beginning of a read operation in addition to the current byte being read, as well as where a write operation began and the current byte being written to. This lets me roll back changes in the buffer if I need to (like dropping entire messages that were cut off due to overflow), and preventing a write operation from running into bytes that are part of an ongoing read operation but have already been read so that I don't end up with half messages.

Comment: @DKNguyen i'm keeping ring buffer solely for storing the user inputs. I'd parse it into a separate array. I could read upto the end of the ring buffer size but that would defeat the purpose of a ring buffer as opposed to a linear buffer I guess. Parsing the new data from the ring buffer isn't an issue (as long as it's within the ring buffer size), but copying into a local buffer for parsing kind of is specially when the older data exists (which has a longer length than that of the new data so old data wasn't completely overriden)

Comment: @jonk don't you thihnk it's inefficient to be reading every byte being put into ring buffer as opposed to reading all at once upon the receipt of `\r`?

Comment: @Pokloha If you provide a very specific and exact code sample for me to look at, which illustrates what you consider efficient, I'll give you an opinion.

Answer (score 2):

Ring buffers use modulo arithmetic.  To move the head index on by one, add one, then modulo the buffer size.  The same for the tail index.  To work out the current string size, it's head minus tail modulo the buffer size (in other words, if the result comes out negative, add the buffer size).

Actually, there's a possible off-by-one error there.  If head is the next entry that you *will write*, then the length of the string so far is `(head - tail) mod buffer_size`.  If head is the last entry that you *have written*, then it's `(head - tail + 1) mod buffer_size`.

The data you want to process is always from tail to head.

It's up to you to handle buffer overflow errors.  You need to detect head catching up with tail to spot the error.  You need to allow for the possibility that someone will send you a string that's longer than your buffer.  There is no magic solution.

Comment: yeah so you're running the risk of losing your old data if the user sends you a longer byte than the buffer size considering the data hasn't been read. And i'm using the power of 2 approach so didn't have to deal with the empty/full buffer conditions. It just nicely wraps around but my current concern is having to deal with old data in the local buffer where the ring buffer data is parsed in case the incoming data is of smaller length

Comment: Clearing the local buffer after each read sounds like one solution but not sure if it's the most feasible option

Comment: @Pokloha You don't ever need to clear the buffer.  Everything between tail and head is valid data.  Anything not between tail and head (or in other words anything between head and tail - it's circular) is old data and can be ignored.  If you are thinking of claring things between messages, then you don't even need a ring buffer - an ordinary array is simpler and a lot less error-prone to implement.